# Ionic FileTransfer from camera Error Code : 3 to server hosting

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, continuous-integration

I have code for upload image from camera to server (LOCAL) and it's work normally

```
fileTransfer.upload(imageData, 'http://192.168.0.100/profile/upload', options1).then((data) => {
                    // success
                    alert("Success");
                }, (err) => {
                    // error
                    alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
                });
```

and then I change the URL from local to hosting, but I get error like this

```
error {"code":3, "source":"file:///storage/...","target":http://mylink.com/profile/upload,"http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":"unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp_Address@51fa1429"
```

how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `chunkedMode: false` in options. and code like this

```
let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
                    mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
                    httpMethod: 'POST',
                    chunkedMode: false,
                   fileKey: 'file'
                }
```